# ¿Cómo realizar una secuencias de "Group_by" de manera mas optima en R?

Tags: r, group-by

Tengo el siguiente Dataset

```
data = data.frame(Id = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"),
                  Date = as.Date(c("2020-01-12","2020-01-30","2020-03-12","2020-01-12",
                                   "2020-01-17","2020-02-12","2020-02-20","2020-01-01",
                                   "2020-01-21","2020-01-30","2020-02-11","2020-02-12","2020-03-01")),
                  Amount = round(runif(13,100,200)),
                  N_Trx = round(runif(13,1,10))) %>% 
  mutate(month = month(Date),
         Week = isoweek(Date)) 

  Id  Date       Amount  N_Trx month Week
   A 2020-01-12    117     6     1    2
   A 2020-01-30    140     9     1    5
   A 2020-03-12    147     1     3   11
   B 2020-01-12    187     2     1    2
   B 2020-01-17    193     2     1    3
   B 2020-02-12    188     8     2    7
   B 2020-02-20    167     8     2    8
   C 2020-01-01    195    10     1    1
   C 2020-01-21    152     5     1    4
   C 2020-01-30    158     2     1    5
   C 2020-02-11    134     7     2    7
   C 2020-02-12    135     8     2    7
   C 2020-03-01    102     2     3    9
```

Quisiera agrupar los ID por dia, mes y semana calcular algunas estadísticas, teniendo una salida como esta:

```
Id Time Median_Amount Median_N_Trx 
 A  Day   ?     ?       ?
 A  Wee   ?     ?       ?
 A  Mon   ?     ?       ?
 B  Day   ?     ?       ?
 B  Wee   ?     ?       ?
 B  Mon   ?     ?       ?
 C  Day   ?     ?       ?
 C  Wee   ?     ?       ?
 C  Mon   ?     ?       ?`
```

Intente hacer varios group_by por separa pàra al final unirlos, pero quizas exista una manera más optima de calcularlo.

Por dia

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarise(Amount = median(Amount), N_Trx = median(N_Trx))
```

Por Mes

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Id,month) %>% 
  summarise(Amount = sum(Amount), N_Trx = sum(N_Trx)) %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarise(Amount = median(Amount), N_Trx = median(N_Trx))
```

Por año

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Id,Week) %>% 
  summarise(Amount = sum(Amount), N_Trx = sum(N_Trx)) %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarise(Amount = median(Amount), N_Trx = median(N_Trx))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que yo sepa, al menos por el lado de `dplyr` no hay forma de generar múltiples subtotales. Podrías sí, reducir bastante el código, si generas grupos por cada sumarización y los terminas promediando al final:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarise(Tipo = "Day", Amount = sum(Amount), N_Trx = median(N_Trx)) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    data %>% 
      group_by(Id,month) %>% 
      summarise(Tipo = "Mon", Amount = sum(Amount), N_Trx = sum(N_Trx))
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    data %>% 
      group_by(Id,Week) %>% 
      summarise(Tipo = "Wee", Amount = sum(Amount), N_Trx = sum(N_Trx)) 
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Id, Tipo) %>%  
  summarise(Amount = median(Amount), N_Trx = median(N_Trx))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Id [3]
  Id    Tipo  Amount N_Trx
  <fct> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     Day     528    5  
2 A     Mon     264    7.5
3 A     Wee     179    5  
4 B     Day     647    3  
5 B     Mon     324.   6.5
6 B     Wee     170.   3  
7 C     Day     874    6.5
8 C     Mon     293    7  
9 C     Wee     143    7
```